# GrailsApplication in Domain Class

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to write the following:

```
import grails.core.GrailsApplication

class MyDomainClass{
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication
    String otherName
    
    String getName(){
        String prop =  grailsApplication.config.getProperty('my.property.from.application.yml')
        return prop + otherName
    }
    static mapping = {
        autowire true
    }
}
```

However, if I have grailsApplication in the domain class the grails command `grails run-app` does not start the webserver and waits forever. It outputs the following warnings, but no error:

```
> IDLE
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/Users/martin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.14/f0a005fb21e7bd9b7ebf04cd2ecda0fc8f3be59d/groovy-2.5.14.jar) to method java.util.AbstractMap.clone()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/Users/martin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.14/f0a005fb21e7bd9b7ebf04cd2ecda0fc8f3be59d/groovy-2.5.14.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
```

Is this some kind of bad practice or a bug? How can I address this issue? The most obvious choice would be in my opinion a call to a service.

I am using the following Grails version:

```
| Grails Version: 4.0.11
| JVM Version: 11.0.11
```

Comment: The A in grailsApplication is capitalized in your variable definition but not when it is used.

Comment: I don't know if it's "wrong" to put grailsApplication in a domain class, but it's certainly unnecessary.  You can use `grails.util.Holders.config` anywhere to access config, and it's going to be simpler and cleaner than injecting grailsApplication.

Comment: declare  `grailsApplication` transient. Also it looks like you want to define the `name` property in `static transients` block

Answer (score 2):

Add the WebAttribute Trait and then you get the grailsApplication included.

> **[9.1.1 WebAttributes Trait Example](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/traits.html#example)**
>
> WebAttributes is one of the traits provided by the framework. Any
> Groovy class may implement this trait to inherit all of the properties
> and behaviors provided by the trait.
>
> `src/main/groovy/demo/Helper.groovy`:
>
> ```
> package demo
>
> import grails.web.api.WebAttributes
>
> class Helper implements WebAttributes {
>
>     List<String> getControllerNames() {
>         // There is no need to pass grailsApplication as an argument
>         // or otherwise inject the grailsApplication property.  The
>         // WebAttributes trait provides access to grailsApplication.
>         grailsApplication.getArtefacts('Controller')*.name
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: This is definitely the way to do it in any other kind of class, but it fails for the domain class. Actually, I am surprised, that it does not start the webserver if we access `grailsApplication` in this way. I decided to access the config via `grails.util.Holders.config` proposed by @Daniel.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me in Grails 3.2.12 but Holders seems just as good and maybe even the best solution.